# How to format output in Perl?

Tags: perl, text, formatting

I have a Perl code responsible for formatting output. Problem is I need to calculate correct number of tabs to be put before one particular character in each string (let's say it's /). So instead of getting  lines with different lengths I'd like to get fixed-length strings (but as short as possible, using the longest as max). How should I approach this?

Example of output (with format commented out, just raw array):

> ```
> Long title with some looong words / short text
> Another title / another short text
> ```

I need it like this:

```
title with some looong words / short text
Different title              / another short text
```

This was my first attempt, but it didn't involve using tabs after one particular character.

```
my $text = Text::Format->new;

$text->rightAlign(1);
$text->columns(65);
$text->tabstop(4);

$values[$i] = $text->format(@values[$i]);
```

Comment: 1. Iterate all strings to find max length 2. Insert tabs into other strings to match previously found max length 3... ? 4. Profit

Comment: Please add some example data. It's hard to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two generally accepted ways to format text in Perl, so columns line up:

- Use `printf` and `sprintf`. This is probably the most common way it's done.
- Use [Perl Format](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) capabilities. You define what you want a line to look like, then use [write](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write.html) to print to that format.

I haven't seen people use Perl Format specifications stuff in years. It was a big feature back in Perl 3.x heydays because Perl was mainly used as a super-awk replacement language(**P**ractical **E**xtraction and **R**eporting **L**anguage). However, the mechanism is still there, and I'm sure it'll be fun to learn.

---

Now comes the second part of your query. You really don't merely want the text to be formatted, you want it to be ***formatted with tabs***.

Fortunately, Perl has a built in module called [Text::Tabs](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/Text/Tabs.html). It's one of those modules that does one or two obscure tasks, but does them well.

Actually, `Text::Tabs` doesn't handle the two tasks it does well, but adequately.

Produce your report using `sprintf` or the build in Perl formatting capabilities. Save your whole report in an array. It has to be an array because `Text::Tabs` doesn't handle NLs. Then use the `unexpand` function to replace spaces in that array into another array with tabs.

**WORD 'O WARNING**: `Text::Tabs` does something very naughty: It imports the variable `$tabstop` into your program without asking your permission. If you use a variable called `$tabstop`, you'll have to change it. You can set `$tabstop` to be the number of spaces a tab represents. It's set to 8 as a default.

Answer (score 0):

The module [Text::Table](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aTable) might help you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::Table;

my @array = ('Long title with some looong words', 'short text',
             'Another title',                     'another short text');

my $table = Text::Table::->new(q(), \' / ', q()); # Define the separator.
$table->add(shift @array, shift @array) while @array;
print $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find in the documentation Text::Format only does paragraph formatting. What you want is a tabular format. The basic approach to that is to split your data into a matrix of text for each row & column, find the longest element for each column, and use that to output fixed width data. e.g.:

```
my @values = (
    'Long title with some looong words / short text',
    'Another title / another short text',
);

# split values into per-column text
my @text = map { [ split '\s*(/)\s*', $_ ] } @values;

# find the maximum width of each column
my @width;
foreach my $line (@text) {
    for my $i (0 .. $#$line) {
        no warnings 'uninitialized';
        my $l = length $line->[$i];
        $width[$i] = $l if $l > $width[$i];
    }
}

# build a format string using column widths
my $format = join ' ', map { "%-${_}s" } @width;
$format .= "\n";

# print output in columns
printf $format, @$_ foreach @text;
```

This produces the following:

```
Long title with some looong words / short text        
Another title                     / another short text
```